# How to iterate through many columns for a value that is not NaN using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, nan

I have an empty column that is dependent on other 4 columns in the same df. Each row only contain the same string or NaN so I want to grab the first string that pops up in the columns.

I want to iterate through the 4 columns and if one of them contain a value that is not NaN, I want to print it in empty, if they're all NaN then I want empty to be NaN.

| empty | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | NaN | NaN | **apple** | NaN |
|  | **duck** | NaN | **duck** | NaN |
|  | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |

This is my desired outcome.

| empty | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **apple** | NaN | NaN | **apple** | NaN |
| **duck** | **duck** | NaN | **duck** | NaN |
| NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `.bfill(axis=1)`:

```py
df["Empty"] = df.loc[:, "1":].bfill(axis=1)["1"]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Empty     1   2      3   4
0  apple   NaN NaN  apple NaN
1   duck  duck NaN   duck NaN
2    NaN   NaN NaN    NaN NaN
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Andrej Kesely ! You made it so simple! Could you help explain to me what the ["1"] at the end of line #1 means?

Comment: @ChewyN The `["1"]` takes the filled values from column `"1"` and places them to `df["Empty"]`